# What are some good installer for windows?

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I am writing a installer for my company's software. The specs is pretty tight: doesn't require administrator rights, good if it also include auto-update capability, have a nice UI (as opposed to the normal windows wizard UI), small and fast, robust...

I looked at Advanced Installer, which satisfy everything except having a good UI. (it shows the classic MSI installer UI which is super-duper old). We would love to have something more user-friendly.

Do you have any suggestions for installers I should look at, given these constrains?

P.S: i'm reading about Google's Omaha next, then maybe NSIS and InnoSetup / WIX...

Comment: The licensed versions of Advanced Installer have themes and a better looking UI: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

This question is very subjective. However Office 2007, 2010, Visual Studio 2012 (aka VS11) were all developed using [WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/). The software is fully open source and you can take a look at the latest weekly release for an example with a very nice UI.

Answer (score 0):

Amm .. I couldn't understand if you want to develop it by yourself, or using another software, but if you do, I think that `Install creator pro` can be good for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We wanted to have a 3rd party, off the shelve software to package our software into installer. The requirements is mentioned in the question. I looked at Install Creator briefly and it doesn't look all that different from Advanced Installer, also, it doesn't seems to be mentioned on dev forums like StackOverflow.